# Getting Error npm ERR! errno 50 while installing Ionic

Tags: android, node.js, ionic-framework

Hello I tried making Ionic App using node.js 
first time I successfully made the simple Hello World Project in ionic
Next day because of the some reason i have to re-install the node.js 
now when i am trying to make ionic app It's giving me an error

```
   Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.32 (ia32) and npm.

C:\Users\SABA-PC>npm install -g ionic gulp
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\SABA-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\ionic\node_modules\.bin'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\SABA-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\ionic\node_modules\.bin']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\SABA-PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic
\\node_modules\\.bin' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic" "gulp"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\SABA-PC
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\Users\SABA-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modul
es\.bin
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\SABA-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\ionic\node_modules\.bin'
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\SABA-PC\AppData\Roami
ng\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\.bin'
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'C:\Users\SABA-PC\AppData\R
oaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\.bin']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 50,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\SABA-PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\
node_modules\\ionic\\node_modules\\.bin' }
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

In my Environment Variable Path=`C:\Users\SABA-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm` 
i tried location the folder `C:\\Users\\SABA-PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\
    node_modules\\ionic\\node_modules\\.bin`

which is saying **Access is denied** eventhough i am running node.js as a administrator

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your node or npm as you've said you had to reinstall it. Try to change the location of your npm cache by running this command:

```
npm config set cache C:\Users\SABA-PC\AppData\Roaming\nodejs\npm-cache --global
```

And read more about npm updates here:
https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Comment: after running the code you have sent .. i am getting the same error